# My bit logic is too outdated. Refresher needed

Tags: math, hardware, bit-manipulation

It's been a while since my assembly class in college (20 years to be exact).

When someone gives you a number, say 19444, and says that X is bits 15 through 8 and Y are bits 7 through 0... how do I calculate values of X and Y?

I promise this is not homework, just a software guy unwisely trying to do some firmware programming.

Comment: Are you programming in assembly language (which one?) or something else (C/C++)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all convert the input number to hexadecimal:

```
19444 => 0x4BF4
```

Hex is convenient because every 4 binary bits are one hex digit. Hence, every 2 hex digits are 8 bits, or a byte. Now assuming traditional little-endian notation (look it up!), bits 7 downto 0 are the low byte, bits 15 downto 8 are the high byte:

```
   [7:0] => 0xF4
   [15:8] => 0x4B
```

Comment: Endianness is irrelevant (unless you're accessing individual bytes using pointer or union magic - which may be happening if this stuff is coming from a serial line etc.).

Comment: @Artelius: I beg to differ. With some interpretations of endinaness, [7:0] (or rather [0:7]) would be the high byte. It is **very** relevant

Comment: @Eli - can you give an example? In my experience, bits 0..7 are always the least significant byte - it's only the position of that byte in memory that varies based on endianness. If that's wrong, I'd like to know how much I need to worry about it.

Comment: @Steve314: some processors specify their words as reg[0:31], where bits [0:7] are the high byte of the register and so on

Comment: After doing some reading it seems Eli is right (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_numbering), but it seems braindead to me. IMO bits should always be numbered based on the power of 2 of their place value; this would greatly reduce complications resulting from endianness and word size.

Comment: @Artelius: it's called "endianness" for a reason - a pun made by Johnathan Swift in his Gulliver books on the "brain-dead" debates about the end of the egg from which to start eating it. :-)

Comment: @Eli - "Some processors" isn't an example. But from Artelius comment, I guess you're right.

Answer (score 3):

Using your preferred language, you can get the least significant byte by using a bitwise AND:

```
Y = 19444 & 0xff
```

or, the more mathematical:

```
Y = 19444 % 256
```

Now, for the most significant byte you can use bit shifts (if the number is larget than two byte, apply the first stage again):

```
X = 19444 >> 8
```

Answer (score 3):

(The following assumes C notation).  In general, to access the value in bits N through M, where N is the smaller value and the bits are numbered from 0, use:

```
(value >> N) & (1U << (M - N + 1)) - 1;
```

So for bits 0..7, use:

```
(value >> 0) & (1U << 8) - 1
```

and for bits 8..15, use:

```
(value >> 8) & (1U << 8) - 1
```

Note that for the case where "N through M" is the entire width of the type, you can't use the shift as written.

Answer (score 1):

Also, mind the byte order (wheter the most significant byte comes first).

Comment: Not in this case. *Bit* numbering might be relevant though.

Comment: Byte order is not relevant here as there has been no mention of memory addresses.

Answer (score 1):

When given bit positions (like "15 through 8"), by convention bit 0 is the least significant bit of the binary number. If you're dealing with a 16-bit number, then bit 15 is the most significant bit.

One hexadecimal digit corresponds to 4 binary digits. So hex `FF` is `11111111` in binary. Bitwise AND is often used to "mask out" a certain collection of bits.

Nearly all processors provide some form of bitwise shifting. For example, shifting `1010001` right by 4 bits gives you `101`.

Combining all this, in C you would typically do something like this:

```
unsigned short int num;
unsigned char x, y;

num = 19444;

y = num & 0xff; //use bitwise AND to get 8 least-sig bits
x = num >> 8;   //right-shift by 8 bits to get 8 most-sig bits
```